# Mostrar la fecha en mi alertDialog

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo un formulario hecho en Android con Kotlin y lo hice con `alrtDialog`. Y mi problema es que estoy intentando cargar la fecha que se me muestra cuando le doy click en el botón cambiar que se pueda mostrar en el `alertDialog` pero no se carga y se cierra la aplicación cuando le doy en OK al que intento mostrarla en el `txtCalendar` para posteriormente mostrarla en el apartado de del código `activity` me gustaría saber como hago eso de mostrarla en el `alertDialog` y que también posteriormente se me imprima en el `activity`.

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos_personales)


 btnMostrar.setOnClickListener {
     val mDialogView =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_contact_data, null)
     val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setView(mDialogView)
         .setTitle("Datos de COntacto")
     val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
     mDialogView.btnSigu.setOnClickListener{
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
         val telefono = mDialogView.editTextTextTelefono.text.toString()
         val correo = mDialogView.editTextTextCorreo.text.toString()
         val pais = mDialogView.autoCompleteTextViewPais.text.toString()
         val ciudad = mDialogView.autoCompleteTextViewCiudad.text.toString()
         val direccion = mDialogView.editTextTextDireccion.text.toString()

         txtTelefono.setText("Telefono: "+telefono)
         txtCorreo.setText("Correo: "+correo)
         txtPais.setText("Pais: "+pais)
         txtCiudad.setText("Ciudad: "+ciudad)
         txtDireccion.setText("Direccion: "+direccion)


     }
 }

    btnPersonalData.setOnClickListener {
        val mDialogView =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_personal_data, null)
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(mDialogView)
            .setTitle("Datos Personales")
        val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
        mDialogView.btnSiguiente.setOnClickListener{
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
            val nombre = mDialogView.editTextTextPersonName.text.toString()
            val apellidos = mDialogView.editTextTextPersonName2.text.toString()
            val sexo = mDialogView.radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId.toString()
            val fecha = mDialogView.txtCalendar.text.toString()
           // val escolaridad = mDialogView..text.toString()

            txtTelefono.setText("Nombre Completo: "+nombre+" "+apellidos)
            txtCorreo.setText("Sexo: "+sexo)
            txtPais.setText("fecha: "+fecha)
            //txtCiudad.setText("Ciudad: "+ciudad)



        }

    }



}
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
fun funDate (view: View){
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        txtCalendar.text ="$dayOfMonth, $monthOfYear $year"
    }, year, month, day)

    //show datepicker
    dpd.show()
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el codigo no veo donde llamas a funDate(), para poder pasar algun valor a un textView por ejemplo dentro de un dialog tenes que hacer un findViewById y pasarlo a una variable para poder usarlo luego de que esta inflada esa vista. sino no funciona, ya me paso y no entendia porque fallaba.

```
val txtCalendarVal = mDialogView.findViewByiD<TextView>(R.id.textCalendar)
```

Tampoco entiendo bien para que haces esto

```
  val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
     
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()

//tendrias que hacer solo esto
mBuilder.show()
//el dismiss no lo veo necesario
```